# correct way to use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager in HttpClient4 getting issue java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am utilizing HTTPclient4 in Java to send HTTP requests and handle HTTP responses. I want to use connectionPooling for improved performance but I am not able to find a proper way to do it.

I am utilizing HTTPclient4 in Java to send HTTP requests and handle HTTP responses. Below is a code sample illustrating how I set up the connection manager and use it to obtain an instance of the CloseableHttpClient:

```java
// Setting up the connection manager
static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();

// Getting the CloseableHttpClient using the same connection manager
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                                .build();
```

However, after using the httpClient and then closing it, I encountered the following error on trying to get a new httpClient from the connectionManager:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
```

Upon investigation, I discovered that closing the CloseableHttpClient also closes the connection manager, leading to this issue.

I understand that connection pooling is recommended when obtaining an httpClient. However, the current behavior poses a question: How can we reuse the same connection manager to get an httpClient if closing the httpClient also closes the connection manager? Additionally, if we cannot reuse the same connection manager, then how does connection pooling work effectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't close the `CloseableHttpClient`. It doesn't have any claimed resources itself, that all goes through the connection manager.

Alternatively, call `setConnectionManagerShared(true)` on the builder. From its API documentation:

> Defines the connection manager is to be shared by multiple client instances.
>
> If the connection manager is shared its life-cycle is expected to be managed by the caller and it will not be shut down if the client is closed.

Comment: > It doesn't have any claimed resources itself, that all goes through the connection manager // Not quite. HttpClient with a caching layer must be properly closed in order to correctly de-allocate cache resources. There are other cases when HttpClient may start extra threads that also need to be properly terminated.

Comment: @ok2c you're probably right. I almost always use a singleton `HttpClient` / `CloseableHttpClient` that I close when the application shuts down.

Comment: For whoever may be interested, regarding closing CloseableHttpClient, the httpclient 5 migration from Apache includes this: "IMPORTANT: Always re-use CloseableHttpClient instances. They are expensive to create, but they are also fully thread safe, so multiple threads can use the same instance of CloseableHttpClient to execute multiple requests concurrently taking full advantage of persistent connection re-use and connection pooling."